# Having problem in grasping a feature of Directive Principle of State Policy

Tags: constitution, democracy, india

I am reading 'Indian Polity' by M Laxmikanth, chapter on 'Directive Principles of State Policy'.

Please explain the following Stanza with help of an example

"The Supreme court has ruled many a times that in determining the constitutionality of any law,if a court finds that the law in question seeks to give effect to a Directive Principle,it may consider such law to be 'reasonable' in relation to Article 14(equlaity before law) or Article 19(six freedoms) and thus save such law from unconstitutionality "

Comment: This sound more appropriate for [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) than Politics.SE.

Comment: @Alexi I think issues of basic constitutional principles are proper in either forum. Yes, constitutions set forth legal rules but they are also the fundamental elements of the political order and allocate power within the political system.

Answer (score 1):

The general meaning of this is that the Supreme Court has a precedent of upholding laws that are admittedly not directly constitutional, based on the fact that it help raise the standards of the constitutional values which include equality and the 6 freedoms.

Comment: Welcome to Politics! Please try to add references to support your answer.